# Acessibility on Ajax Checkbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, accessibility

I have a [bootstrap switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) checkbox which triggers an Ajax call. However, its functionality is pretty important and I need to ensure that it will work in any browser. I have a url that handle the request. What I need to know is how can I make the checkbox a "link" to this url if javascript is not enabled.

Note: I don't have a submit button.

Comment: Have the link in place on page render and remove it with javascript/replace it with the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks @JesseKernaghan.. if you want, you can add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd be less worried about making the widget available to those who do not have JavaScript enabled, and more worried about failing to meet [WCAG 2.0 - 3.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20-20051123/#consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change) - Changing the setting of any input field does not automatically cause a change of context

Comment: @steveax you mean if, for some reason, the ajax call does not work? I will change the setting of the input only on success.

Comment: @GabrielMoretti, in a nutshell, that WCAG success criteria says that you should not change the user's context (navigate, change the screen contents, etc.) when a form control (select, radio, checkbox, etc,) changes value, but rather have a button to request the change. Changing the context without the additional action of submitting the change might be surprising and confusing.

Comment: @steveax I see your concern.. But that may be changing? I mean, youtube has a "switch" like this one to activate/deactivate autoplay. However, it is not a core function. With your experience, should I really worry about this issue, or it is just a nice guideline?

Comment: @GabrielMoretti, I'm can't comment from a legal POV, but would note that in the U.S. the section 508 refresh is close and will essentially be WCAG 2.0 AA. [3.2.2 is an A level criteria](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/Overview.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the link in place on page render and remove it with javascript/replace it with the checkbox. This ensures that it's available to those without javascript.